# Checkout Form - How to wrap multiple elements in a class - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, forms, uicomponent

How do you wrap two checkout form elements inside a div?

**For example let's say I wanted to wrap these country and zip/postcode fields in a div with the class of `example-class`, how would I do this?**

[image]

### What I have tried

I tried to achieve this by adding them as children of `<item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">` but that just causes errors on the frontend. Although I did get a blank text input without a label inside `.example-class` there were errors on the frontend.

The error: `Cannot read property 'indexedOptions' of undefined`

This is my quick attempt:

**Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-address/form.html**

```
<div id="shipping-new-address-form" class="fieldset address">
    <div class="testing">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('example-class') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </div>
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('additional-fieldsets') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->
</div>
```

**checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<item name="example-for-adding-class" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
        </item>
    </item>
    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">example-class</item>
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <!-- The following items override configuration of corresponding address attributes -->
        <item name="region" xsi:type="array">
            <!-- Make region attribute invisible on frontend. Corresponding input element is created by region_id field -->
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </item>
        <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/region</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
                <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.region</item>
            </item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <!-- Value of region_id field is filtered by the value of county_id attribute -->
            <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="target" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id]]></item>
                <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
            </item>
        </item>
        <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
            <!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
        <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

There has to be an easier way to do this, either I'm missing something or this is the definition of over-engineering. Adding a div over two elements should never be this difficult.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Very interesting question.
Let me answer the last assumption about the Checkout implementation. It might be over-engineered a bit since you have to add more than just 1 change in 1 file.

*The approach does not require performing modifications in the Magento 2 core modules.*

In order to achieve your goal and wrap checkout shipping address fields into a custom  element the following elements should be added:

1. Custom checkout_index_index.xml file with the new UI Component definition
2. New HTML template with custom  element
3. Layout Processor plugin
4. The di.xml declaration for the new plugin

The **Custom_Checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="custom-field-group" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Custom_Checkout/checkout/field-group</item>
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="field-group" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">field-group</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

In the layout, we should add new **custom-field-group** UI Component. The component has its own template **Custom_Checkout\view\web\template\checkout\field-group.html** where all fields are rendered. Also, the **custom-field-group** component has "0" value for **sortOrder** node. It allows rendering the component before all fields declared as part of the **shipping-address-fieldset** component.

Also, there is a **field-group** UI Component with its own **displayArea** setting.

The **Custom_Checkout\view\web\template\checkout\field-group.html** template file:

```
<div class="custom">
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('field-group') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
</div>
```

The template allows rendering all components added into the **field-group** region (also known as **displayArea**).

The **Custom\Checkout\Plugin\AddressLayoutProcessor** class file:

```
namespace Custom\Checkout\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor;

/**
 * Class AddressLayoutProcessor
 */
class AddressLayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(LayoutProcessor $subject, array $jsLayout)
    {
        $fieldGroup = &$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']
            ['children']['custom-field-group']['children']['field-group']['children'];

        $shippingAddressFields = &$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'];

        $fieldGroup['country_id'] = $shippingAddressFields['country_id'];
        $fieldGroup['postcode'] = $shippingAddressFields['postcode'];

        $shippingAddressFields['country_id']['visible'] = false;
        $shippingAddressFields['postcode']['visible'] = false;

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

The class is responsible for copying both **country_id** and **postcode** fields configurations into the newly created **custom-field-group** component.

The fields, once assigned to the **custom-field-group** should be marked as hidden (visible = true) in order to avoid duplication during rendering. The **componentDisabled** should not be used for disabling country_id and postcode due to other dependencies (e.g. region.js file) and shipping address processing mechanism.

The **Custom\Checkout\etc\frontend\di.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="customFieldGroupPlugin" type="Custom\Checkout\Plugin\AddressLayoutProcessor"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

The plugin approach used for the fields changes because fields should be copied with complete configuration. In case Layout Processor declared in a custom module the plugin will catch changes.

As a result, both the **country_id** and the **postcode** fields are rendered in the shipping address form and wrapped into the custom  element as it below (I added few styles for the **custom** CSS class to make stand out in the form):

[image]

If you also would like to do modifications to a billing address form, the **Custom\Checkout\Plugin\AddressLayoutProcessor** class should be updated. All you have to do is to perform same manipulations with billing address for specific payment method as we have for shipping address fields.

Happy to help!

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I would have never have managed that, interesting how it requires backend work to. I was tackling this from a purely FE point of view. If no one comes up with a simpler solution in a few days (as I think some other people are currently looking at this) I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks again.

Comment: Excellent answer :)

Comment: Awesome, Thank you so much. It Works for me.

Comment: If I want to same change applies to the new billing address then?

Comment: If you also would like to do modifications to a billing address form, the Custom\Checkout\Plugin\AddressLayoutProcessor class should be updated. All you have to do is to perform same manipulations with the billing address for the specific payment method as we have for shipping address fields.

Comment: Thank you for the reply :-)
Could you please give me one example?

Comment: Hello @MaxPronko could you please help me regarding billing address wrapper?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a recommended way, it's simple but not elegant:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
          <block class="Vendor\Salesman\Block\Checkout\Index" name="custom_checkout" before="-" template="Vendor_Module::checkout/index.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/Lime/Salesman/view/frontend/templates/checkout/index.phtml

```
<script>
  require([
      'jquery',
      'mage/mage'
  ], function($){
      $(document).ready(function () {
         //detect if the shipping form container loaded
         var existCondition = setInterval(function() {
            if ($('#shipping').length) {
              moveElement();
            }
         }, 100);

         function moveElement(){
             //get The field postcode and country
             var postcodeField = $("div[name='shippingAddress.postcode']");
             var countryField = $("div[name='shippingAddress.country_id']");
             // insert the wrapeer
             $( '<div class="wrapper"></div>' ).insertBefore( postcodeField);
             // move the fields to wrapper
             $(".wrapper").append(postcodeField);
             $(".wrapper").append(countryField);
         }
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I've upvoted as I'm confident it would work but I agree it isn't very clean, I wouldn't use this unless there was no cleaner method. Thanks.