# Add Custom Header In Checkout Shipping

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address

I am trying to add custom headers to the checkout process to break the forms up into sensible sections.

I have already modified `checkout_index_index.xml` to alter the sort order of my form. It now looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">40</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="company" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">45</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

How do you go about adding headers in to break the form up in the following way

[image: New H3 tags added above First Name Field and Address entry Point]

In the attached image I have converted the labels to placeholders within the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Brother Try this

Create checkout_index_index.xml at

> app/design/frontend/Package/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper"/>
        <move element="catalog.topnav" destination="content" before="-"/>
        <move element="minicart" destination="header-wrapper"/>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false" />
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container"  remove="false"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now flush cache and try...!

Answer (score 0):

@Speedingorange - Did you got answer for your query ? 
I am looking for the same . Kindly share if you have any info about this

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have a dev working on the site currently and will add a snippet to explain if it works.

Comment: I got this one usefull - It not perfectly suite the requirment but we can group the element in wrapper

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186805/checkout-form-how-to-wrap-multiple-elements-in-a-class-magento-2