# How to wrap multiple elements in a div - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout

I'm trying to separate the checkout fields into divs but in this module, I found that the HTML template doesn't exist.

I'm using this link [Checkout Form - How to wrap multiple elements in a class - Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186805/checkout-form-how-to-wrap-multiple-elements-in-a-class-magento-2/200925#200925)

But get the error: Template not found.
This is my repository with module complete for anyone see:
https://bitbucket.org/israelguido/custom_checkout_m2/src/master/

Comment: Please check the file path and also verify that it will be generated in pub folder the same path.

Comment: Yes, dosen't generated in path. This is repository of module https://bitbucket.org/israelguido/custom_checkout_m2/src/master/

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed your module and found below thing you need to update.

- web/template/checkout/field-group.html should be come under frontend/web/template/checkout/field-group.html.

After the update, please run a static-content command and let me know if you are still facing the same issue.

Hope above solution will work for you.

Comment: I had already tested this possibility, but still not generate my module

Comment: Please email me I will try to look into it: nitish250788@gmail.com